# Reactjs : Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.5

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Now, I met this issues when I use Reactjs and "contentEditable" or "edit" mode of html5.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p data-reactid=".0.5">Reactjs</p>
</div>
```

When I type Enter or Shift Enter to new line -> Make new same element with the previous element

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p data-reactid=".0.5">Reactjs</p>
<p data-reactid=".0.5"></p>
</div>
```

When i click in theses elements -> this error will appear.

I know that is an issue. Can someone give me the solution for it?
Maybe create new another element in "contenteditable" mode, or prevent handle implicit event in Reactjs.

THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1466

Using `<div contentEditable dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<p></p>'}} />` is the only workaround for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved this problem using `key = {some random string}` for new element.